# Directive 'recompilation' into another

Tags: angularjs

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to accomplish this kind of attribute directive:

```
<p my-attr-directive="ABC">go to ABC</p>
```

should be recompiled in a ui-router parameterized link:

```
<p ui-sref="param_state({id:'ABC'})">go to ABC</p>
```

The state `param_state` is fixed, the new directive should defines the parameter `id`.

**EDIT**: I almost done, I'm not sure why $compile, doesn't compile

```
<a href="#" my-attr-directive="2a"> LINK!!</a>



app.directive('myAttrDirective', function($compile) {
     return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, el, $attrs) {
            $attrs.$set("uiSref","param_state({id:'"+$attrs.myAttrDirective+"'})");
            $compile(el.contents())($scope);

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I almost done, I'm not sure why $compile, doesn't compile

If you inspected the anchor element, you'd see something like the following in it,

```
<span class="ng-scope">LINK!</span>
```

which means `$compile` has done its job. In this regard, just binding the contents of the element (i.e. the `textNode` 'LINK!') to the `$scope`.

Therefore, `$compile` ***is*** compiling, but it hasn't found your dynamically added directive `uiSref` anywhere searching.

```
 $compile(el.contents())($scope); // <== your directive exists as an attribute of `el` itself
```

## Solution

Try to compile the host `element` itself since you add the `uiSref` directive there as an attribute. Also, its important to remove the `my-attr-directive` attribute from the element or else you'll end up infinitely compiling the anchor element:

```
link: function($scope, el, $attrs) {
    // make sure you don't recursively compile
    el.removeAttr('my-attr-directive');

    $attrs.$set("uiSref","param_state({id:'"+$attrs.myAttrDirective+"'})");
    $compile(el)($scope);  // <== here
}
```

### [*Working Demo*](http://plnkr.co/edit/sUW4HlJHKKE9TsAl2ZeE?p=preview)

Comment: Maybe this directive I wanted is a real overkill, but I hope to be able to move few business logic in it..

Comment: You haven't mentioned as to why do you need to set some parameter in the `uiSref` like that.